# FP in Scala book: Stream.apply is strict?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

In section 5.2 `Stream.apply` defined:

```scala
  def apply[A](as: A*): Stream[A] =
    if (as.isEmpty) empty else cons(as.head, apply(as.tail: _*))
```

and, seems to me, this removes property of lazy evaluation of Stream elements. For example, following test fails:

```scala
  describe("a Stream") {
    describe("laziness") {
      it("should work") {
        import Stream.cons

        def producer(i: Int, ab: ArrayBuffer[Int]): Int = {
          ab.addOne(i)
          i
        }

        val ab1 = ArrayBuffer[Int]()

        // apply is strict in book ?!?!
        val stream1 = Stream(producer(1, ab1), producer(2, ab1), producer(3, ab1))

        ab1 should be (Nil)

        stream1.toList should be (List(1, 2, 3))
        ab1 should be (List(1, 2, 3))
      }
    }
```

You'd need manually assemble stream to make laziness work:

```scala
        val stream1 = cons(producer(1, ab1), cons(producer(2, ab1), cons(producer(3, ab1), Empty)))
```

So, the question -- is this intentional or some oversight? Book errata doesn't mention `apply`, but I still can't figure out why.

Answer (score 2):

Indeed, `Stream.apply` is not lazy. It is because method parameters `as: A*` must be initialised before passed to the method. There is nothing the called method can do to make it lazy after that.

Consider following examples.

Given this generation function

```scala
var i = 0

def next() = {
  i = i + 1
  i
}
```

Let's init Stream in two different ways

```
val notLazy = Stream.apply(next(), next(), next())
println(i)

val partiallyLazy = Stream.iterate(next())(_ => next())
println(i)
```

It will print `3` and `4` respectively. It shows that method `apply` has to have all three parameters initialised before it's executed. And in case of `iterate`, it has to have the `head` initialised as well.

Let's consider now `LazyList` introduced to replace Stream in `2.13` and see that it has quite similar behaviour.

```scala
i = 0

val nonLazyList = LazyList.apply(next(), next(), next())
println(i)

val lazyList = LazyList.iterate(next())(_ => next())
println(i)
```

This will print `3` and `3`. This shows that `apply` method has the same non-lazy behaviour as in `Stream` with deference in `iterate` where `head` becomes lazy.